# Ruby 1.9.3 Digest::SHA1.hexdigest equivalent in Golang

Tags: ruby, go, hex, sha1

How can I replicate this method from Ruby 1.9.3 to Golang 1.7?

```
require 'digest/sha2'
text = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("Hello world")
```

Comment: perhaps https://gobyexample.com/sha1-hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [crypto/sha1](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha1/)

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := sha1.New()
    s.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
    fmt.Printf("%x", s.Sum(nil))
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bWWP-679fed)